# Get proportion between two columns after dplyr group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame as follows

```
Endo   Proc    Adenoma  
1      Colon    Y
1      Colon    Y
1      Colon    N
2      Colon    Y
2       OGD     N
3      Colon    Y
3      Colon    N
3       OGD     N
```

I want to find the proportion of `Proc` which are Colon and have Y for the `Adenoma`, grouped by `Endo`.

At the moment I am using long winded code as follows:

```
    MyColonDataAdenomaDetectionByEndoscopist <-
      dataframe[grep(".*[Aa]denom.*", dataframe[, Adenoma]),]

    MyColonDataAdenomaDetectionByEndoscopist <-
      MyColonDataAdenomaDetectionByEndoscopist %>%
      group_by_(Endo) %>%
      do(data.frame(NumAdenomas = nrow(.)))

 MyColonDataADR <-
      full_join(
        MyColonDataAdenomaDetectionByEndoscopist,
        MyColonDataColonoscopiesByEndoscopist,
        by = Endo
      )
    MyColonDataADR$PropAdenomas <-
      (MyColonDataADR$NumAdenomas / MyColonDataADR$NumColons) * 100
```

I am sure I can shorten this down. I want in the end to have it as a function as I do several similar things later on.

The problem I have is the ability to do two groupings in one `dplyr` pipe (I group to see all the `Proc` called `Colon` done by each `Endo` and then just group by the number of `Colon` that are also positive for `Adenoma` by each `Endo` and then divide one by the other to get the proportion.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: @A.Suliman Please post as an answer. Of course...divide by n. But is that dividing by the number of rows that have Colon in them or the number total number per endo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Endo) %>% 
  summarise(Co_por=(sum(Proc=='Colon' & Adenoma=='Y')/n())*100,
            Nobs=n(),Pat_Col=sum(Proc=='Colon')) 

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    Endo Co_por  Nobs Pat_Col
   <int>  <dbl> <int>   <int>
1     1   66.7     3       3
2     2   50       2       1
3     3   33.3     3       2
```

From `?dplyr::n()`

> The number of observations in the current group.